# jackson deserialize object with list of spring's interface

Tags: java, spring, redis, jackson

I need to save and load objects from redis.

The object contains list of GrantedAuthority (among other things) which is an interface:

```
public class UserAccountAuthentication implements Authentication {
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    private boolean authenticated = true;
    ...
}
```

Jackson successfully serializes the object but fails to deserialize it with the following exception:

```
abstract types can only be instantiated with additional type information
```

I know that I can specify the type by adding:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
```

But I can't do it in this case because the `GrantedAuthority` is an interface of Spring and I cannot change it.

---

the serialized json is:

```
{
"authorities": [
    {
        "authority": "ROLE_NORMAL_USER"
    }
],
"authenticated": true,
"securityToken": {
    "expiration": 1458635906853,
    "token": "sxKi3Pddfewl2rgpatVE7KiSR5qGmhpGl0spiHUTLAAW8zuoLFE0VLFYcfk72VLnli66fcVmb8aK9qFavyix3bOwgp1DRGtGacPI",
    "roles": [
        "ROLE_NORMAL_USER"
    ],
    "expired": false,
    "expirationDateFormatted": "2016-03-22 08:38:26.853 UTC"
},
"name": "admin",
"expired": false
```

}

---

the abstract `GrantedAuthority` is only filled with `SimpleGrantedAuthority`.

so i tried:

```
objectMapper.registerSubtypes(SimpleGrantedAuthority.class);
```

and still no luck.

Comment: Did you see if your getters and setters are written properly ?

Comment: there are no getters and setters its a private list that the object works with internally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to add a custom deserializer

```
public class UserAccountAuthenticationSerializer extends JsonDeserializer<UserAccountAuthentication> {

@Override
public UserAccountAuthentication deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
        throws IOException {

    UserAccountAuthentication userAccountAuthentication = new UserAccountAuthentication();

    ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
    JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jsonParser);
    userAccountAuthentication.setAuthenticated(node.get("authenticated").booleanValue());

    Iterator<JsonNode> elements = node.get("authorities").elements();
    while (elements.hasNext()) {
        JsonNode next = elements.next();
        JsonNode authority = next.get("authority");
        userAccountAuthentication.getAuthorities().add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.asText()));
    }
    return userAccountAuthentication;
}
```

}

This is my json

```
{"authenticated":true,"authorities":[{"authority":"role1"},{"authority":"role2"}],"details":null,"principal":null,"credentials":null,"name":null}
```

Then at the top of your POJO

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = UserAccountAuthenticationSerializer.class)
public class UserAccountAuthentication  implements Authentication {
```

Here's the test

```
@Test
public void test1() throws IOException {

UserAccountAuthentication userAccountAuthentication = new UserAccountAuthentication();
userAccountAuthentication.setAuthenticated(true);
userAccountAuthentication.getAuthorities().add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("role1"));
userAccountAuthentication.getAuthorities().add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("role2"));

String json1 = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(userAccountAuthentication);
UserAccountAuthentication readValue = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json1, UserAccountAuthentication.class);
String json2 = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(readValue);
assertEquals(json1, json2);
```

}

Comment: I followed your code step by step and got it compiling, but when its running the "deserializer" never breakpoints as if it never runs and I am getting this error: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.coronet.online.security.GrantedAuthorityContainer out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@4db4a5cb; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: com.coronet.online.security.UserAccountAuthentication["authorities"])

Comment: Can you post your json, I've added the Jason used in my test.

Comment: Also what implementation of GrantedAuthority are you expecting to use?

Comment: only SimpleGrantedAuthority...im now trying to do something like: objectMapper.registerSubtypes(new NamedType(SimpleGrantedAuthority.class, "GrantedAuthority")); ... but no luck so far

Comment: I changed my test to reflect your code, it works fine, can't see the problem.

Comment: can you please update it in your answer maybe i missed something or did it wrong?

Comment: I've updated my answer to be as close as possible to your question, good luck.

Comment: Thank you, it is working and was supposed to work before also i just had jackson codehaus instead of fasterxml as import for the ObjectMapper.. and it didn't work. Thank you again :)