# "Bad Request" when sending JSON object to Rest service

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I'm writing a web app in Java Spring. I have got this MyUser class shown below and a rest API.

```
public class MyUsers {
    String username;
    String password;
    boolean enabled;
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> roles;

    //getters, setters
}
```

Some methods in UserController:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
ResponseEntity createUser(Principal principal, @RequestBody @Valid MyUser user) {
    ...
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{username}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody MyUser getUser(HttpServletResponse response, Principal principal, @PathVariable("username") String username) {

   ...
}
```

From the GET method I recieve this json:

```
{
    "password":"5345345345",
    "enabled":true,
    "roles":[{"authority":"ROLE_ADMIN"}],
    "username":"admin"
}
```

However, when I use the POST method, I can't specify the role, I can only send an object which is below, otherwise I get a "Bad Request" error.

```
{
    "password":"5345345345",
    "enabled":true,
    "roles":[],
    "username":"admin"
}
```

I want to be able to specify the roles.
Any ideas on how to fix this issue will be highly appreciated.

EDIT:

I tried this, but it doesn't help. Is there a mistake?

```
public class UserDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<MyUser> {

    @Override
    public MyUser deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
            throws IOException {

        MyUser MyUser = new MyUser();

        ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jsonParser);

        Iterator<JsonNode> elements = node.get("roles").getElements();
        while (elements.hasNext()) {
            JsonNode next = elements.next();
            JsonNode authority = next.get("authority");
            MyUser.getRoles().add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.asText()));
        }
        //System.out.println(MyUser.toString());
        return MyUser;
    }
}

@JsonDeserialize(using = UserDeserializer.class)
public class MyUser{
    String username;
    String password;
    boolean enabled;
    List<GrantedAuthority> roles;

    //getters, setters
}
```

Comment: Looks like Jackson has difficulty in deserializing Spring security `GrantedAuthority` object. You can try using a Jackson custom deserializer for this.

Comment: Of course [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35724693/jackson-deserialize-object-with-list-of-springs-interface) post might be helpful to you,

Comment: Well, I tried but have some problems, should I put @JsonDeserialize annotation in the MyUser class?

Comment: Yes because you've to tell Jackson to use this specific one to deserialize it. Another approach would be to set a custom [SimpleModule](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/module/SimpleModule.html) to default objectMapper used by Spring in MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter class, This class is used when serializing and deserializing objects with `@ResponseBody` and `@RequestBody`. You may create new `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` with your own ObjectMapper if you want. But first approach is far easier I think

Comment: I still can't get it to work, it seems that deserialize method is not accessed. I added the code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your updated code, you've used `@JsonDeserialize` on the `MyUser` class, This is I think not necessary as Jackson already knows how to deserialize all fields of `MyUser` class except `roles` field. I'm suggesting to use `@JsonDeserialize` at the `roles` field level so that you don't have to deserialize the entire `MyUser` class, just only the field Jackson cannot deserialize.

As an advantage, if you ever wish to add new fields, you wouldn't need to modify your custom deserializer, not changing the API is not a good thing to do though.

Something like this would be sufficient.

```
public class GrantedAuthorityDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Collection<GrantedAuthority>> {

@Override
public Collection<GrantedAuthority> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    JsonNode jsonNode = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    if (jsonNode.isArray()) {
        // you may have different serialization logic if you want
        for (JsonNode node : jsonNode) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(node.get("authority").asText()));
        }
    }

    return authorities;
  }
}
```

and use `@JsonDeserialize` at `roles` field,

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = GrantedAuthorityDeserializer.class)
Collection<GrantedAuthority> roles;
```

I assume that you have Jackson 2 in your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

GrantedAuthority is an interface, you need to inform the Jackson Library about the concrete class by one of the ways mentioned here

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQ#Deserializing_Abstract_types