# Is there a way to customize serialization of only one specific String typed field of a JPA entity in a Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

I only want custom serialization on a specific String typed field of a JPA entity. For example a field named `details` on an entity class named `User`. The serialization logic needs access to some other Spring beans so those beans should be injected to it.

This JPA object might be the root of serialization or a member of another entity that is to be serialized.

So I think I cannot use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize`. If I define a `org.springframework.boot.jackson.JsonComponent` for the type `String`, it will be invoked for all `String` fields and can have potential negative side effects on the serialization performance/throughput.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35724693/jackson-deserialize-object-with-list-of-springs-interface/35726158#35726158

Comment: _Serialize_, not _deserialize_.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a custom serializer for a `String` field. In this simple example it  just makes it lowercase

```
class DetailsSerializer extends StdSerializer<String> {
    public DetailsSerializer() { this(null); }
    public DetailsSerializer(Class<String> t) { super(t); }

    @Override
    public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        jgen.writeString(value.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

The important bit is to annotate the particular field so that this serializer is used for this field only. E.g.

```
class User {
    @JsonSerialize(using = DetailsSerializer.class)
    private final String details;

    // other fields getters etc.
}
```

Comment: Hi, as I have mentioned in the question I need to inject other Spring beans into the serializer (in this case, the `DetailsSerializer`).

Answer (score 0):

EntityListeners are eligible for injection, you can declare a callback for the load event in the listener and pass whatever bean you need to the entity

```
public class MyListener {
  @Inject MyBean bean;

  @PostLoad
  public void inject(MyEntity entity) {
    entity.bean = bean;
  }
}
```

And your entity:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(MyListener.class)
public class MyEntity {
  public @Transient MyBean bean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have annotated your deserializer with `@JsonComponent`, which makes Jackson have it the default deserializer for every String.

Remove that annotation, and annotate the fields you want deserialized with that custom deserializer, with `@JsonDeserializer(using = MyDeserializer.class)`.

This makes Spring call that JsonDeserializer (through Jackson, not sure how they work in a lower level) only for the field you want deserialized with your deserializer.